# Как вернуть значения только из некоторых полей MongoDB c помщью C# одним запросом

Tags: c#, база-данных, asp.net-core, mongodb

Например у меня есть "MongoDB" база данных с такой структурой:

```
    person: {
     _id: <ObjectId>,
     name: "Ivan",
     age: "30",
     position: "accountant",
     city: "Moscow"
}
```

Как я могу вернуть элементы из базы например только полям ***position*** и ***age*** - **ОДНИМ** запросом в базу? Я знаю как это сделать за пределами базы, вернуть всю коллекцию и отсеять по нужным элементам, но нужно что бы фильтрация происходила в запросе в базу и все операции по фильтрации происходили в ней.

Я находил примеры с несколькими запросами, там создавали фильтр *FilterDefinition* и запрашивали элементы по каждому полю, но для меня такой способ не подходит, потому что полей может быть и не 2 а 20 и 50 и 100. Если это важно проект asp net core, mongodb c#.

Answer (score 1):

Не работал с MongoDB, но нашел инструкцию с [сайта метанита](https://metanit.com/nosql/mongodb/4.7.php):

> С помощью стандартных операций программирования конъюнкции, дизъюнкции
> и логического отрицания мы можем комбинировать запросы. Например,
> фильтр на всех документов у которых Name=Bill, либо Name=Tom:

```
var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
var filter = builder.Eq("Name", "Bill") | builder.Eq("Name", "Tom");
var people = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```